# Formatting object of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm taking data through an API and have this structure:

```
    "key1" : {
            "subkey1" : value
            "subkey2" : value
            "subkey3" : value
         }
"key2" : {
            "subkey1" : value
            "subkey2" : value
            "subkey3" : value
            "subkey4" : value
            "subkey5" : value
         }
"key3" : {
          "subkey1" : value
          "subkey2" : value
          "subkey3" : value
          "subkey4" : value
         }
```

For a specific component, I need to make one expansion panel for each "key" , with inside this once opened a table formatted as follows (without headers):

```
 (accordion) key 1
```

If I open the expansion panel it shows the first table with the data "contained in key1"

```
   subkey 1 | value
   subkey 2 | value
   subkey 3 | value


 (another accordion) key2

   subkey 1 | value
   subkey 2 | value
   subkey 3 | value
   subkey 4 | value
   subkey 5 | value
```

I need to know both how to have the data saved in variables in the right way in the .ts file (the API is already done) and how to format everything in HTML.

Comment: Hi, your question as it stands appears to be asking the community to do all of your work for you. What have you tried so far, and where has it failed to produce the desired result?

Comment: I created an object and filled it with the data that came back from the api (not sure if in the right way)

Then I created this structure 

<mat-table [dataSource]="infomatricolaobj">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let object in infomatricolaobj">
            <td mat-cell> {{infomatricolaobj.keys[object]}} </td>
            <td mat-cell > {{infomatricolaobj.values[object]}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-table>

Inside an extendable panel, wrong for sure, but i'm new in this world and i'm trying to learn

Comment: @WillAlexander I'm not trying to get the job done.
I'm just asking for some help on this like all the people on this blog do.

Comment: You haven’t shown what you’ve tried and where it has failed. You’re asking multiple questions in one, and have simply said “I need to know how to do this and this”. That’s not how to ask a good question here on SO. I suggest you read the good question guide.

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't solve completely your question, but I hope it helps:

To get the interfaces from your json you can use [json2ts](http://json2ts.com).

Then you just need to use `const myTsObject: MyInterface = JSON.parse(myJson)` to convert your json to typescript object.

Then you can call it in your html like this:

```
<div>{{myTsObject}}</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the structure of the data that returns from the API